# Show image in Square grid (React + Material UI Grid)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I use React + `[Material UI Grid][1]` to show my images, the images are in different sizes, and I want to:

1. Keep image ratio
2. Make image fit the parent container square(in other words, all images in a row with the same height)

The problem is that, The number of columns in Grid is variant, sometimes 3 columns(on mobile) and sometime 6 columns(on PC), React calcuate the width of image Dynamically. I don't know the run-time image width, so i can not set the image height in my css style excatly. any idea? thanks.

You can see the following effect currently, a very tall image makes the grid streched vertically, very ugly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-frost-hgsmy?file=/src/App.js). It centres the image inside the `Grid` and doesn't let it overflow while also not giving the dim in pixels. Although the dimension is fixed to square(a x a) but can be changed.

I had the same issue in the past so I am sharing my own code.
Hope this will be useful as I have used `CardMedia` with component type `img`. You can select the relevant `CSS` if not complete from inspecting.

Comment: Oh i forgot to signup on codesandbox. The project must be visible now.

Comment: Bounty will be transfered in 16 hours, thanks.